# Ruby: getting different substrings from string and putting into variables

Tags: ruby

I have the following string in a textfile :

String:

`38561 2914 55532, (aggregated by 55532 202.52.118.114)`

Using ruby, how do I read the above string and do the following:

1. Extract just the substring `55532` from the line and put into a `aggregator` variable?
2. Extract `38561 2914 55532` and put into a `paths` variable?

I'm trying to use a combination of `string.scan` and `string.split` with not much luck.
All the substrings I would like to extract will change in real life, but they will always be integers. I'm especially struggling to get the `aggregator` variable populated (task 1) - trying to find a way to get it by starting with `[aggregated by ]` and ending with `[ ]` but couldnt get it to work so far. Task 2 (`paths` variable) I could achieve with regex, but trying to do both Task 1 and Task2 in a single read/scan, if it makes sense.

Any ideas?

Appreciate it,
J

Comment: Do you wish to extract `'55532'` because it is the first string of digits to be folllwed by a comma? If so, use `str[/\d+(?=,)/]`, `(?=,)` being a positive lookahead. If that is that is not the criterion for extracting `'55532'`, what is? Do you wish to extract `'38561 2914 55532'` because it begins the string and is followed by a comma? If so, `str[/\A[\d ]*\d(?=,)/]`. Please edit to clarify.

Comment: What is the code you are having trouble with? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ? Please, provide a [mre]. Please be aware that [so] is not a code-writing service, you need to show your efforts!

Comment: "couldnt get it to work so far" is not a precise enough error description for us to help you. *What* doesn't work? *How* doesn't it work? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ?

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/ https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/ https://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/ https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/ https://idownvotedbecau.se/noexceptiondetails/

Comment: Wow, harsh.  I guess its deserved probably. I did say that I tried various combinations with split and scan so I thought it was obvious from this comment that I did attempt before asking. I appreciate the input though - although harsh comments like these do put people off asking genuinely for help. Be kind.

Comment: Jane, half the battle in answering a question is stating the question in a precise, unambiguous manner, which was the point of my comment. I assume the objective is not to extract the string literal `'55532'` if it appears in the string, but to extract a string of digits that meets some criterion. Here are four possible criteria: 1) the first string of digits followed by a comma; 2) the third string of digits; 3) the first string of digits beginning with a `'5'`; and 4) the first string of digits followed later in the string by the same string of digits. When you are close to a question...

Comment: ...you've been working on, the criterion may seem obvious but it may not be to others. I suggest that after having stated a question, but before posting, you be a devil's advocate by looking for possible ambiguities. Once you are satisfied that it could not be misunderstood, the answer may become obvious or you are at least closer to it. I hope you will stick around and post more questions at SO, in which case soon enough you'll be posting comments and then answers yourself.

Comment: Thanks Cary. Completely understand. yes it is hard when you're close to it and I did try to make a point that `55532` is not literal by saying `All the substrings I would like to extract will change in real life, but they will always be integers.` but agree I could be clearer.  i think its amazing that people can be so helpful taking their time to help. I just think sometimes (and I go a lot of stackoverflow for hints) that some people are very harsh when criticizing/downvoting and spend so much time doing this (pointing out the wrongs) instead of just helping, so it is a fine balance.

Comment: @JaneD : Then, please show what you tried. BTW, you are asking two different problems: (1) How to read a piece of information from a file, and (2) how to parse it. If you have two different problems, please ask two questions.

Comment: Hmm I'm pretty sure I know how to read the info from a file. I'm unsure what you meant by `(1) How to read a piece of information from a file`. My question has been answered below and no he did not have to outline how to read it from file. I am right now spending more time trying to 'perfect' my questions than trying to actually code. But I think we all have agreed that I should ask better questions next time so I will try to do my best (about to post another question actually) so no point trying to "show what I have tried" here, I will do that in the next questions :) case close

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach with `split`

```
line = "38561 2914 55532, (aggregated by 55532 202.52.118.114)"

numbers, aggregatedBy = line.split(", ")

paths = numbers.split(" ") # => 3856,2914,55532
aggregator = aggregatedBy.split(" ")[2] # => 55532
```

Comment: This works Fabio - I did not even think of that the comma could be used as a divider in this case, for some reason that pattern just didnt jump out. Tired I guess! Really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

If the string starts with three integers, you can use `scan` and `each_slice` like this:

```rb
irb> str = '38561 2914 55532, (aggregated by 55532 202.52.118.114)'
irb> paths, aggregator = str.scan(/\d+(?=[ ,])/).each_slice(3).to_a
irb> paths
=> ["38561", "2914", "55532"]
irb> aggregator
=> ["55532"]
```

or:

```
arr = str.scan(/\d+(?=[ ,])/)
paths, aggregator = [arr[0..-2], [arr[-1]]]
```